Threshold energy formula
In Krane's Introductory Nuclear Physics, in chapter 11, he uses the conservation of energy and momentum to derive the formula for the threshold energy of a reaction a + X → b + Y (with X being an immobile target) in the lab frame as:
$$T_{a,th} = -\frac{m_Y+m_b}{m_Y+m_b-m_a}Q$$
Where $Q$ is the Q-value defined as $Q=\left[(m_a+m_X)-(m_Y+m_b)\right]c^2$, and for which we had to assume we weren't in a relativistic scenario.
Later on, however, in chapter 15, he presents the formula for the threshold energy in the CM frame as:
$$T^*_{a,th} = -\frac{m_a+m_X+m_Y+m_b}{2m_X}Q$$
But, from what I've been able to tell (from the Wikipedia page on Threshold Energy), we can only get to this using Lorentz transformations, so how come I could assume non-relative rules before and now I can't? Can anybody shed some light on this?

why dont you just compute it correctly in the SR case and be done with it?
